# Remove "selected" from an option of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a form. One of my colleagues have used the are_you_sure.js which confirms to leave before saving a form.

Now the problem is if I have a dropdown say like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_cpc(cst_type)
 {
    if(cst_type==0 || cst_type==1)
    {
      $("#camp_cpc").show();
      $("#camp_cpc").val("'.(!empty( $html['camp_cpc'] )?(double)$html['camp_cpc']:'').'");
    }
    else
    {
      $("#camp_cpc").hide();
      $("#camp_cpc").val("0");
    }
}
</script>



<select name="cost_type" id="cost_type" onchange="get_cpc(this.value);" class="ultra-select">
     <option value="0">CPC</option>
     <option value="1" selected="selected">CPA</option>
     <option value="2">Do Not Track</option>
</select>
```

When I am switching from non-selected options to selected option, then the change of state takes too much time

This means if I am selecting CPC/Do Not Track from CPA, then the dropdown works fast. But if I am selecting CPA from CPC/Do Not Track, then the state change takes almost 4 seconds..

That's due to the jquery.are-you-sure.js. So, I need to remove the select from the dropdown. How can I achieve this?

I put this code, `$("select option").prop("selected", false);`
but it doesn't even let me select any other option.

Comment: You can do `.removeAttr("selected")`. But the best thing to do is to debug and correct the faulty JS. I bet that, obviously, you don't have any access or permission on the buggy JS, and you have to deal with it and find a dirty workaround...

Comment: Saswat, there's an answer here from March - was it useful at all? The upvote is mine, so it looks like you've not voted on it or replied to the helpful person who has offered assistance.

Comment: I had already found the answer before he had posted. So, it wasn't helpful to me, because I already found out the answer. However you are right, he did try to help. So I can give him an upvote. But can't accept the answer.

Comment: @Saswat, that's OK: acceptance isn't mandatory. However, I think some acknowledgement of help is a useful social nicety - if everyone ignored helpful posts, the site would largely cease to function. (Please use at-names such as `@halfer` when replying, otherwise a notification is not raised).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean exacly, but can you share the `are_you_sure.js` file?¿

Also I have change your code maybe it helps and it´s a better way to do it. because it´s not a good practice use `onchange()`, so remove onchange from your html and do this, link: http://jsfiddle.net/hg5nz1w6/1/

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cost_type').on('change', function(){
        var cst_type = $(this).val();
        if(cst_type==0 || cst_type==1)
        {
          $("#camp_cpc").val("'.(!empty( $html['camp_cpc'] )?(double)$html['camp_cpc']:'').'");
          $("#camp_cpc").show();
        }
        else
        {
          $("#camp_cpc").hide();
          $("#camp_cpc").val("0");
        }
    });
});
```

html:

```
<select name="cost_type" id="cost_type" class="ultra-select">
     <option value="0">CPC</option>
     <option value="1" selected="selected">CPA</option>
     <option value="2">Do Not Track</option>
</select>
```

Below you can see some examples to remove the selected:

```
document.getElementById('myselect').selectedIndex = -1;
```

you can deselect all the options:

```
$("select").val([]);
```

or

```
$("select option").prop("selected", false);
```

Hope it´s helps!